# only one video card in use when rendering

Tags: rendering, video, gpu

I am using Blender 3.01 . When rendering it looks like there is only one video card in use. only one bucket shows.
However using blender 2.93lts shows the two bucket..... ???

Any idea what is happening?
In the preferences both cards are checked and recognized by the system

Any help is welcome
Thanks

Felipe

Comment: Hi :). Do you mean only one tile? Since Blender 3.0 all GPUs work on a single tile at once.

Comment: Yes only one tile ...

Comment: It look like one gpu des not have any load as read in GPU-Z

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I did not pay attention to the full message... now i know that .....Since Blender 3.0 all GPUs work on a single tile at once. Thanks a lot